# How to create Generic if @EnvironmentObject?

Tags: xcode, swiftui, xcode11.4

I've recently come across the need to write a Mock of a `Class`, as it causes the SwiftUI `preview` from working. Unfortunately, I get the error:

```
Property type 'T' does not match that of the 'wrappedValue' property of its wrapper type 'EnvironmentObject'
```

In the View struct:

```
struct ContentView<T>: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var mockFoobar: T
    ...
}
```

And also the error:

```
Type of expression is ambiguous without more context
```

For the Preview struct:

```
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        let mockFoobar: MockFoobar = MockFoobar()
        return ContentView<MockFoobar>()
            .environmentObject(mockFoobar)
    }
}
```

The MockFoobar class is:

```
class MockFoobar: ObservableObject {
  ...
}
```

As the user @Asperi kindly provided, tested the following as suggested:

```
class Foobar: ObservableObject {
    @Published var param: Bool = false
    func start() {
        self.param = true
    }
}

struct MyFoobarView<T: ObservableObject>: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var foobar: T
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello Foobar")
        }
        .onAppear {
            self.foobar.start()
        }
    }
}

struct MyFoobarView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        let foobar: Foobar = Foobar()
        return MyFoobarView()
            .environmentObject(foobar)
    }
}
```

But I get the following errors (the first in the `.onAppear` and the second in the PreviewProvider):

```
Cannot call value of non-function type 'Binding<Subject>'

Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred
```

Comment: If it works fine what’s the question? And what’s the “mock” part? Looks real to me.

Comment: You're right, let me delete the Simulator stuff, as that was meant to show that the initialisation process worked in that context; but is not a Generic. The "mock" part is mainly to explain the need to use a  Generic to represent the environmentObject; Mock as in, has the same interface as Class  "Foobar"; but I need to mock "Foobar" to avoid some CoreAudio stuff that stops Preview from working

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The EnvironmentObject must be ObservableObject, so here is fix

```
struct ContentView<T: ObservableObject>: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var mockFoobar: T
    
    // .. other code here
```

**Update:** added demo with introduced model protocol

```
protocol Foobaring {
    var param: Bool { get set }
    func start()
}

class Foobar: ObservableObject, Foobaring {
    @Published var param: Bool = false
    func start() {
        self.param = true
    }
}

struct MyFoobarView<T: ObservableObject & Foobaring>: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var foobar: T

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello Foobar")
        }
        .onAppear {
            self.foobar.start()
        }
    }
}

struct MyFoobarView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        let foobar: Foobar = Foobar()
        return MyFoobarView<Foobar>()
            .environmentObject(foobar)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Even when the Class MockFoobar is of type ObservableObject? It's not inferred?

Comment: @punkbit, tested & worked with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4. I assume there is something else out of provided code in question.

Comment: Ok cool! So, I double-checked but I get two error messages (updated the original post). I'll keep looking into this to figure it out and hopefully update it with an answer.

Comment: @punkbit, see updated - added demo with specific protocol.

Comment: Yeh, appreciate it! Conforming to Protocol and ObservableObject is the solution!

Comment: how could we do something like `.onReceive(foobar.$param)` ?