# How to use Swinject to register protocol conforming to ObservableObject?

Tags: swift, swiftui, protocols, combine, swinject

Right now, I've been running into an issue of registering protocol conforming to `ObservableObject`. Since `ObservableObject` uses an associated type, I cannot find a way to register it without compiling error.

This is my simple model, called A

```
protocol A: ObservableObject {}
```

This is my simple class, called B

```
final class B: A {}
```

Here is my Assembly

```
final class ViewStoreAssembly: Assembly{
    func assemble(container: Container) {
        container.register(A.self) { _ in
            B()
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to register A comforming to ObservableObject, but the compilation error shows that

> Protocol 'A' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has
> Self or associated type requirements

Does anyone know how to tackle the issue? The benefits of doing this will be

1. In SwiftUI, we can decouple view out of ViewStore/presenter so that view can be separated from viewModel holder
2. ViewStore/Presenter can be tested easily by mocking a view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to use instead the following combination (anyway `ObservableObject` has sense only for classes, and it brings nothing for model protocol itself, and it is not possible to have observer, like `ObservedObject`, around protocol)

```
protocol A {}

final class B: ObservableObject, A {}
```

I assume the following topics can be helpful as well:

[How to define a protocol as a type for a @ObservedObject property?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59504489/12299030)

[How to create Generic if @EnvironmentObject?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61972798/12299030)

Comment: interesting, thanks !